# Intersection of line and plane in 3d - solving

Tags: geometry

In 3D space,

$ax+by+cz=d$ represents a plane, and,

$px+qy=r$ represents a line.

In my visualization, a line and a plane intersects only at a point.

And one more thing, I know(not sure if it truly has a proof) is - `you need n equations to solve n unknowns`.

Doesn't these became contradictory?

How can I solve these two equation ?

Comment: The single equation $px+qy=r$ in the space $\{(x,y,z):\ x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a plane, perpendicular to the $XY$-plane. You need two equations like this to determine a line.

Comment: Your second equation is also a plane, it is just parallel to the  $z$-axis and the coefficient in front of $z$ is zero.

Comment: You will need a line in 3D

Comment: How can I solve these two equation ?

Comment: Solve the second equation for $y$ in terms of $x$, and substitute the result in the first equation to solve for $z$ in terms of $x$.  There are infinitely many solutions, corresponding to the intersection line, so the best you can do is express them in terms of a single variable.

Comment: Make for the equation of a straight line the ansatz$$\vec{x}=\vec{x_0}+s\vec{a}+t\vec{b}$$